# Adjust imageview position using coordinates in the original background image

Tags: android, imageview

[image]
I have a image, with a cut out in it. I know the bounds of the cutouts in the original image.

I am trying to fit a face inside this cut out.

How can I do that and use these values for various screen densities.

The code I am currently using is below. It does not achieve the goal, it shows the image as a small thumbnail, which gets fixed to top

RelativeLayout linearLayout =  (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.root);

```
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


    relativeParams.leftMargin =273;
    relativeParams.topMargin = 509;
    relativeParams.rightMargin = 672;
    relativeParams.bottomMargin = 1031;


    //relativeParams.setMargins(300,300,300,300);

    ImageView iv = new  ImageView(this);

    iv.setImageBitmap(Constants.userBit);



    linearLayout.addView(iv, relativeParams);
```

Comment: I have added the image. I need to be able to fit the face within the mouth of the area. The dimensions are the rectangular bounds of the mouth on the original image

Comment: I will try that and update. Thanks